# Cannot create an instance of interface type

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-standard-2.0

I'm getting an error when trying to map a DTO to an Object and I'm not sure why.

I created NUnit tests against my libraries which are all .NetStandard 2.0 and it all works and tests are passing.

Please [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/eugeneniemand/80ec6926494f02b9539944c9db4cff5d) (please note these are just grouped together for illustrative purposes, my code is actually spread across different files and projects)

Now here is the problem, unit tests pass however when I call the ToSettings method with the exact same values for the parameters etc from my UWP app I get an error on the two lines where I do the mapping

```
settings = mapper.Map<SettingsDto, ...>(dto);
```

This is the Exception for NZ

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot create an instance of interface type 
MyLifePlan.Interfaces.ISettings_NZ.
Parameter name: type
 at lambda_method(Closure , SettingsDto , ISettings_NZ , ResolutionContext )
 at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
 at MyLifePlan.Model.Converters.ToSettings(SettingsDto dto)
```

I get something very similar for UK but on the TaxBracket

Comment: What is the the configuration of Autofac ?

Comment: Sorry this is actually an AutoMapper issue I got the library names mixed up

Comment: You map a class to an interface. It can't instantiate the interface. Do you have an implementation of this interface ?

Comment: But why would the unit tests work but calling the same code from UWP raise an exception?

Comment: Do you use stub or change the context in the unit tests ?

Comment: Not at all, I load the same json from disk and deserialise into the DTO then call the ToSettings method on the exact same DTO. In the tests it works but from UWP I get an exception. Also your comment about mapping to an Interface you will notice in the config I'm using the ConstructUsing and a class that implements the corresponding interface.

Comment: @EugeneNiemand never mind. just saw the gist

Comment: I've run your code and I don't see it, so a real repro would be nice. The way this code looks I'm wondering how can you ensure that Initialize is only called once.

Comment: @lucian what do you mean the initialize is only called once? surely this is scope to the method and can run multiple times. I know the code runs as I said it works from my tests but from the UWP side it fails

Comment: That's broken. Initialize should be only called once per appdomain. Newer versions throw when calling it twice. You should upgrade.